# How to hide a column from gridview base on a Sql result on it?

Tags: sql, vb.net, gridview, hide

I'm using VB .NET and I have a GridView which have 4 columns *(Delete, Download, Nome, and PK)*. Columns "Name" and "ID" are a result from my Sql Command, and I want to hide the column "PK" to users. But I couldn't do it. I've tried some codes but nothing.

Here is my code:

```
  Public Sub obterTabela()
        Dim db As DbConnect = New DbConnect()
        Dim conn = New SqlConnection(db.geraConnString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        Dim aux As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query)
        aux = aux.Replace("?id=", "")
        Dim conjunto As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(aux)

        conn.Open()
        'alterar
        cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT nome AS 'Nome', pk_table AS 'PK' FROM t_kml WHERE fk_table = " & aux, conn)

        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        dt.Load(sdr)
        'Dim indice As Integer = (Integer).Parse(dt.Columns("PK"))

        'dt.Columns.Item("PK").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden

        sdr.Close()

        gdv_kml.DataSource = dt
        'gdv_kml.Columns(2).Visible = False
        gdv_kml.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

and

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdv_kml" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" CellPadding="4" 
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Download" Text="Download" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <b>Nenhum KML incluso.</b>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
     </asp:GridView>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `False` and then :

```
Private Sub GridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As System.Object,ByVal e As System.GridViewRowEventArgs )
{
  e.Row.Cells("PK").Visible = False
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way you can exclude PK from your SQL query?
So that you only extract the three columns, without PK

Answer (score 0):

Turn off autogeneratefields and list the fields you want displayed in the  section.